# does git pull atomically write files

Tags: git, version-control

I can't find anything in the documentation.
If I do a git pull, am I guaranteed that the underlying file, resulting of the merge, is atomically written?

Some more context about what I am trying to achieve:
I have some scripts that periodically do a git pull and I need to know if I can rely on the state of the files being valid during a pull.

We are basically using git as a deployment tool. We never have merge conflicts by design. On the remote end, a job constantly pulls every x seconds, and other jobs read the files. What could happen is that we open a file while it's being pulled by git, and the contents of the file are not what we are expecting. 
This is unless git is smart enough to use some atomic swap on the underlying OS (RedHat in this case)

Comment: First of all, what does "valid" mean in that context? It's hard for us to know, since we don't know what you're trying to accomplish. I strongly suspect that if you need to know the state of the file *during a pull*, you're trying to accomplish something that refuses to let git just be a source control tool... so what "valid" means is far from obvious and very important to the question. I can tell you that in the event of a merge conflict, there will come a point where the file stops being "valid code", whether it's atomically written or not.

Comment: you're right, I added some context. Hope it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is *no*.

It's worth considering that `git pull` isn't about files at all, it's about *commits*.  Files are just a side effect. :-)  The pull operation is just `git fetch` (obtain commits) followed by a second Git command, usually `git merge`.  The merge step merges *commits*.  This has a side effect of merging files as well, if the operation is not a fast-forward instead of a merge; and then when the merge or fast-forward is complete, Git does a `git checkout` of the resulting commit.

So this really boils down to: *Is `git checkout` atomic at the OS level?*  The answer is a very loud *no:* it's not atomic in any way.  Individual files written in the work-tree are written one at a time, using OS-level `write` calls, which are not atomic.  Files that need to be created or deleted are done one at a time.  Git *does* use the index, which indexes (i.e., keeps tabs on) the work-tree, to minimize the number of files removed, created, or rewritten-in-place.  Git also locks against other *Git* operations, and makes the Git-level transaction appear atomic—but anything working outside Git, that does not cooperate with Git's locking system, will be able to see the changes as they occur.

Comment: thanks. That's what I was expecting. It could be nice if there was an option to force an atomic swap on the files, but that's probably not what git is designed for

Comment: Note that you can build your own atomicity using separate work-trees (with separate index files) and a `rename` operation, assuming you have an atomic rename. The idea here is to check out the new work-tree (using a new empty index) into an empty temporary directory that can live in the same place as the current tree. You then rename the "in use" tree out of the way, and rename the new tree into place. There is a brief window when there is *no* tree at all, but that's as small as you can get unless your OS offers a "swap names" operation.

Answer (score 1):

On the `git checkout` part of `git pull`, see [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366413/6309).

On the `git fetch` part of `git pull`, there is an [--`atomic` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---atomic),  Git 2.36 (Q2 2022) clarifies it.

"[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/851d2f0ab123c8fa33bbdc8e5a325e0c8b2c5d9c/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> can make two separate fetches, but ref updates coming from them were in two separate ref transactions under "`--atomic`", which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit 583bc41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/583bc419235cedc6a2ba12593f058a9f812b9594), [commit b3a8046](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3a804663c4682f6df55dd6703f8f8af9a7c6ab5), [commit 4f2ba2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f2ba2d06a7dd7e84e105a2779a7f07549d04231), [commit 62091b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62091b4c87a199c172556f15c5662c6c3679e9cd), [commit 2983cec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2983cec0f26b7409ccc2dd5710b40ff4809cd4b1), [commit efbade0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efbade066083eb0a8ccee5a8290cd3fc834705f3), [commit 2a0cafd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a0cafd464709cfa22fe7249290c644a2a26c520) (17 Feb 2022) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 851d2f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/851d2f0ab123c8fa33bbdc8e5a325e0c8b2c5d9c), 13 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a0cafd464709cfa22fe7249290c644a2a26c520): increase test coverage of fetches
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> When using `git fetch` with the `--atomic` flag, the expectation is that either all of the references are updated, or alternatively none are in case the fetch fails.
>
> While we already have tests for this, we do not have any tests which exercise atomicity either when pruning deleted refs or when backfilling tags.
> This gap in test coverage hides that we indeed don't handle atomicity correctly for both of these cases.
>
> Add test cases which cover these testing gaps to demonstrate the broken behaviour.

---

Warning:

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), revert the "deletion of a ref should not trigger transaction events for loose and packed ref backends separately" that regresses the behaviour when a ref is not modified since it was packed.

See [commit 4315986](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43159864b62202b7a887b65e562fba9f45f5cd2e), [commit 347cc1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/347cc1b11dc1082d217a5221fd074e8fb984cdc3), [commit c6da34a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6da34a610e58f7e58042b5ed24a19bd2c18e928) (13 Apr 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4027e30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4027e30c5395c9c1aeea85e99f51ac62f5148145), 14 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`4027e30c53`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4027e30c5395c9c1aeea85e99f51ac62f5148145):Merge branch 'jc/revert-ref-transaction-hook-changes'

> Revert "fetch: increase test coverage of fetches"
> Revert "Merge branch 'ps/avoid-unnecessary-hook-invocation-with-packed-refs'"

---

"[`git fetch --atomic`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/deb67d12de91c0a8fecaee4c6a97f8f1e18b1c5a/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L10)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---atomic))</sup> issued an unnecessary empty error message, which has been corrected with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024).

See [commit 18ce489](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18ce48918cbbdc5091b57f4883f9fe3795b0ce44), [commit 97d82b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97d82b296332f2f4de641f4acbb5ceb4856dcba9) (17 Dec 2023) by [Jiang Xin (`jiangxin`)](https://github.com/jiangxin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit deb67d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/deb67d12de91c0a8fecaee4c6a97f8f1e18b1c5a), 27 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18ce48918cbbdc5091b57f4883f9fe3795b0ce44): no redundant error message for atomic fetch
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jiang Xin</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> If an error occurs during an atomic fetch, a redundant error message will appear at the end of `do_fetch()`.
> It was introduced in [b3a8046](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3a804663c4682f6df55dd6703f8f8af9a7c6ab5) ("`fetch`: make `--atomic` flag cover backfilling of tags", 2022-02-17, Git v2.36.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/851d2f0ab123c8fa33bbdc8e5a325e0c8b2c5d9c) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b896f729e240d250cf56899e6a0073f6aa469f5d)).
>
> Because a failure message is displayed before setting retcode in the function `do_fetch()`, calling error() on the err message at the end of this function may result in redundant or empty error message to be displayed.
>
> We can remove the redundant error() function, because we know that the function `ref_transaction_abort()` never fails.
> While we can find a common pattern for calling `ref_transaction_abort()` by running command "[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/18ce48918cbbdc5091b57f4883f9fe3795b0ce44/Documentation/git-grep.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> -A1 `ref_transaction_abort",` e.g.:
>
> ```
> if (ref_transaction_abort(transaction, &error))
>     error("abort: %s", error.buf);
> ```
>
> Following this pattern, we can tolerate the return value of the function `ref_transaction_abort()` being changed in the future.
> We also delay the output of the err message to the end of `do_fetch()` to reduce redundant code.