# Are git's file writes (in the working directory) atomic?

Tags: git

Are git operations such as `git reset`, `git checkout` atomic at the file level? I'm trying to determine whether it is possible that a file can be in a partially written state while these operations are running. Any pointers to authoritative sources are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I don't think they are. As far as I know git uses  system `read()` and `write`, which shouldn't be relied to be atomic. There is some information on this in the following topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362006/does-git-pull-atomically-write-files

Comment: Should I close as duplicate?

Comment: I was hoping for some authoritative sources (e.g., pointers to source or docs). The earlier question is lacking this. I tried looking but I'm hoping someone with deeper knowledge of git internals can answer.

Comment: The documentation for *your* operating system's `write` system call depends on your operating system, which you failed to mention in your question. You'll need more details.

Comment: I suppose what I'm really asking for is a pointer to the relevant parts of source in git (to really understand what it is doing now), and perhaps get an understanding of why it doesn't write to a temporary file and use a rename. I guess the git mailing list is better for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're asking is whether Git writes to a temporary file and then renames, no, it doesn't do this. Because Git is working with multiple files, there's no way of guaranteeing a checkout operation is atomic, even with renaming files. At any point, a failure could cause an operation to abort with no way to recover. Git may also have to replace files with directories or vice versa in order to perform a checkout, and there's no way to even attempt atomicity there.

Furthermore, the write-aside-and-rename approach doesn't work on Windows, which doesn't allow renaming over existing files.

Git does rely on the atomicity of `read` and `write` as specified by POSIX (e.g. that multiple `write` calls are not interspersed) in other places, but TTBOMK that behavior isn't required in a checkout.